# C++ weird syntax spotted in Aruco codes

Tags: c++, opencv, syntax, aruco

I have found strange syntax in some of Aruco files:

```
vector< cv::Mat > thres_images(n_param1);
```

Seems like `thres_images` is function, but if yes then what is `vector< cv::Mat >` in front of it? It is not declaration nor definition. Later it is used as array:

```
thres = thres_images[n_param1 / 2];
```

PS: full code can be found [here](https://www.arkeon.be/trunk/dependencies/aruco/src/markerdetector.cpp)

Comment: That is simply a vector constructor accepting 1 argument, i.e. it's size. You are crating a `std::vector<cv::Mat>` called `thres_images` with size `n_param1`. Then you access the middle element of this vector

Comment: Looks like a variable definition for me, nothing special.

Comment: I think you need [a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). That's a standard variable declaration calling a specific constructor of the [standard `vector` class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Have you come across `std::vector` before?

Comment: nothing weird about this.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I've never used vector constructor before so this misleads me. Isn't there something like this http://cdecl.org/ for C++ constructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thres_images` is a vector and its ctor is passed `n_param1` as initial container size. This ctor is referred to as a fill ctor.